# Find the minimum value of this integral.

Tags: calculus

Find the minimum value of this integral: For what value of $k > 1$ is 
$$
 \int_k^{k^2} \frac 1x \log\frac{x-1}{32}\, \mathrm dx 
$$
minimal?

After applying Newton-Leibniz, I got $k = 3$ and then did 2nd derivative test, it gave me positive result, thus 3 is the answer but I want to know if there's a smarter/slicker way to do?

Comment: That green hurts my eyes. You can use $\TeX$ on this site, enclosed in single dollar signs for inline formulas and in double dollar signs for displayed equations.

Comment: Sorry sir. I'll take care of it from next time.

Comment: Two answers, but I'm the only person who's up-voted the question so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $I:(1, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
$$
I(k)=\int_k^{k^2}\frac{1}{x}\log\frac{x-1}{32}dx.
$$
Then
$$
I'(k)=\frac{2}{k}\log\frac{k^2-1}{32}-\frac{1}{k}\log\frac{k-1}{32}=\frac{1}{k}\log\frac{(k+1)^2(k-1)}{32}.
$$
We have $I'(k)<0=I'(3)$ for $1<k<3$, $I'(k)>0=I'(3)$ for $k>3$, therefore $I(3)$ is the minimal value of $I(k)$ for $k>1$.

Answer (score 3):

$J=\int_k^{k^2}dx \frac{1}{x}\ln\frac{x-1}{32}=-\operatorname{dilog}(k)-\ln(\frac{k}{32}-\frac{1}{32})\ln(k)+\operatorname{dilog}(k^2)+\ln(\frac{k^2}{32}-\frac{1}{32})\ln(k^2)$
where:
$$\operatorname{dilog}(x)=\int_1^x \, dt \ln(\frac{t}{1-t})$$
The derivative respect to $k$ is:
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial k}=-\frac{1}{k}[5 \ln(2)+\ln(k-1)-2\ln((k-1)(k+1))$$
putting:
$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial k}=0$$
the result is $k=3$